# Render twig file A within twig file B but only when viewing twig file C?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have 3 twig files of components:

File 1:

```
<div class="container">
    {# content-here #}
</div>
```

File 2:

```
<div class="section">
    <h2 class="section__title">{{ title-here }}</h2>
    {# content-here #}
</div>
```

File 3:

```
<a class="mylink" href="{{ link-path }}">{{ link-text }}</a>
```

These files are imported into my website (a seperate repo) and used. I need to keep them in seperatre files (how they currently are) for this to keep working.

Within the same repo as the components I want to make a new page which will be a styleguide guide to demonstrate them:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="section">
        <h2 class="section__title">Title</h2>
        <a class="mylink" href="#">Link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can create arrays within the styleguide to populate the placeholders (eg title-here) but I dont want to repeate the HTML, I want to pull in the components so that the styldeguide updates if the compoents change.

The issue I'm having is that I need to put components within components eg the Section within the Container. I can't just use an include as this will break my site in the other repo which needs to consume the components separately. How can I do this?

One solution would be if the styleguide page could read the `{# content-here #}` and instead interpret it as an include. Can this be done?

Note that I am able to edit the component twig files, but I they need to make sense in there own right as this is how the other website consumes them.

Comment: Is your project written within Symfony framework?

Comment: Its standard Twig so yes.

Comment: I mean, you can use Twig standalone, or Twig within a Symfony application. With a Symfony app you can do lots of tweaks you can't with Twig only... In your case, I would use the Symfony's `render()` function in your styleguide as you look to use your components like widgets.

Comment: Ah sorry, in that case im using Twig standalone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [`embed`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/embed.html)

Here's the solution, with working Fiddle: http://twigfiddle.com/npvcag

file1.html.twig:

```
<div class="container">
    {% block container %}
        {# content-here #}
    {% endblock container %}
</div>
```

file2.html.twig:

```
<div class="section">
    <h2 class="section__title">{{ title-here }}</h2>
    {% block section %}
        {# content-here #}
    {% endblock section %}
</div>
```

file3.html.twig:

```
<a class="mylink" href="{{ link_path }}">{{ link_text }}</a>
```

The styleguide:

```
{% embed "file1.html.twig" %}
    {% block container %}
        {% embed "file2.html.twig" %}
            {% block section %}
                {% include "file3.html.twig" %}
            {% endblock section %}
        {% endembed %}
    {% endblock container %}
{% endembed %}
```

Comment: This is exactly what `embed` was meant to accomplish, and is IMO the best solution if the OP is running Twig ^1.8 and can modify the templates to add `{% block}`.

Comment: I've added a link to the Twig Fiddle showing how this works. :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks terrible, but you may tray something like following.

File 1:

```
<div class="container">
    {{ content | default('') }}
</div>
```

File 2:

```
<div class="section">
    <h2 class="section__title">{{ title }}</h2>
    {{ content | default('') }}
</div>
```

File 3:

```
<a class="mylink" href="{{ link_path }}">{{ link_text }}</a>
```

Styleguide page:

```
{{ include('file1.html.twig', {
    content: include('file2.html.twig', {
        title:   'Title',
        content: include('file3.html.twig', {
            link_path: 'myLink',
            link_text: 'Link'
        })
    })
}) }}
```

Anyway you may save content of the included file into a variable, change it as you need and render then.